# Rotating a icon with css class property

Tags: html, css, rotation

I want to rotate an icon with class property in css

```
.km-cursoricon:after {
content:"\e0d4";
display:inline;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg); }
```

Here i am using content for icon and it is not rotating after using rotate transform also and "km-cursoricon " is the class for that icon, any one can suggest me how to rotate that icon.

Comment: `inline` elements cannot be transformed. You need to set `display` as block level or inline block.

Comment: sorry for same answer,but you write too fast :)

Comment: total icon got hiding while using block or inline-block @Harry

Comment: @ManojKumarMiriyala: You have to add your full code (if possible with a demo) for somebody to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Harry it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements cannot be transformed,and pseudo elements are inline by default so apply `display:block` or`display:inline-block` to transform them

Comment: total icon got hiding while using block or inline-block

Comment: post your code here pls https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: just apply display:inline-block

Comment: It's working now, Thanks